# Phpmyadmin: How to add permanent setting for exporting mysql gzipped by default

Tags: phpmyadmin, compression, gzip, config, settings

There is a setting under `settings > export > compression` for default compression method when you hit "export database" (I want `gzip`).

[image: How to add permanent setting for exporting mysql gzipped by default]

I cannot do it permanent. Every time I restart server it is set back to compression `none` method.

How to make this settings permanent using phpmyadmin config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update config file `config.inc.php` in top-level directory.

Add string

```
$cfg['Export']['compression'] = 'gzip';
```